# Specflow netcore reporting tool

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

Can anyone advise any free specflow html reporting tools. I've tried:

1. Configure allure, but it's not supporting netCore
2. Extent reports, but it's not working with parallel tests
3. Specflow+runer official isn't free for corporation use

My project technology stack:
-netcore 3.1
-specflow 3.7.38
-nunit
-restSharp

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow+ Runner is free. To use it you need an also free SpecFlow Account. We changed that  1 1/2 years ago.

But there is something better than SpecFlow+ Runner.
Have a look at SpecFlow+ LivingDoc (https://specflow.org/plus/livingdoc/).

It looks like this:

[image: SpecFlow+ LivingDoc Example]

There are two versions available. SpecFlow+ LivingDoc for Azure DevOps which integrates into Azure DevOps and SpecFlow+ LivingDoc Generator which is a CLI tool that generates a single HTML file.
I would try the later one.
And at the moment, it doesn't require a SpecFlow Account.

If you have problems with creating a SpecFlow account, please contact our support.

---

Full Disclosure: I am the Community Manager of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.